# .msi and .mst are not digitally signed

Tags: windows-installer, installation, exe, installshield

There is program.msi file which is digitally signed as the path is provided in the installshield but in the installer logs it is showing .msi is not digitally signed as well as for .mst is also not digitally signed. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. You had an original setup.exe that was signed, but when you extracted you got an MSI and an MST that are not signed?

Comment: yeah, when i am referring the logs, it showed that It showed Note:2262 2 Digital Signature .msi , .mst is not digitally signed. And the last line showed Note:1703.